# Methods to find out what remounts /sys readonly (RHEL 6.7)

Tags: rhel, mount, sysfs, linux-audit

A few colleagues intermittently have issues with suspending/hibernating their computers (running RHEL 6.7, normal workstation install, nothing special). As it turned out, the problem was that `/sys` was mounted readonly. It was easily fixed via `mount /sys -o remount,rw` but it was not a one-off issue, it happens frequently.

I'd like to find out what changes sysfs to readonly, but somehow struggling with an appropriate method. From what I remember, `inotifywait` or `inotifywatch` will only show that something has changed regarding a particular inode, but not which process triggered this.

Maybe [auditd](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/01/a-brief-introduction-to-auditd/) could help, although I'm not sure how to restrict the syscalls in a feasible way as this is no real filesystem. Would adding a rule that watches the `mount` and `unmount` syscalls on /sys be sufficient to detect a change in sysfs? E.g. like so:

```
auditctl -a always,exit -F path=/sys -S mount -S umount
```

Apart from that, if any other tool would be more appropriate, or any pointers where this issue could come from would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: would it help adding /sys to fstab?

Comment: sysfs /sys is by default in fstab. And how should that help in finding out what remounts /sys readonly in a running system?

Comment: In Debian it is not, and I force deviations in behavior in /proc, /sys and /etc putting them in fstab. .have a look at sysdig, it might help.

Comment: if this is a VMWare platform, there is a known problem filesystems going read-only on their own, requiring a remount and failing this at times, requiring a reboot. My current environment is not a a RHEL shop, although we have few. Hence, I do not have a current subscription to view subscriber only articles but there was one of those, exactly about this issue. You might consider searching redhat.com.

Comment: @MelBurslan No it's a regular physical installation, and it only happens with /sys which is not a real filesystem, and remounting it does not require a reboot. And I've not found any other mention that suits this issue. Docker containers do mount /sys is readonly on purpose since a few months. Also with systemd, it mounts e.g. /sys/fs/cgroup readonly on purpose. But we have neither systemd nor docker containers.

Comment: I have a couple bad ideas: an infinite loop that checks the mount status (to pin down timing); and wrapping the `mount` binary in a script to check caller status (though this wouldn't catch an internal kernel call)

Comment: @JeffSchaller Bad idea or not - doesn't really matter to me if it's bad when it helps ;) Basically `auditd` should do exactly the same as you suggested with the infinite loop, but it would catch the kernel syscalls and show who triggered them. sysdig would also be a pretty similar approach. And for the mount binary, that might be a fallback idea - thanks for the pointers, appreciated :)